# let i always equals undefined but var i is defined in for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

I am using vue, vuedraggable and vuetify in my project.

I am not able to use let to define my index for my loop it always is undefined. This method is being called by an event from draggable. Using var instead of let works however.
Why is let always undefined?

Even when I directly assign the variable i to 1 it is still undefined. For example for(let i = 1;  i < 2; i++) still results in i being equal to undefined inside the for loop.

This is where I am seeing the issue

[image]

```
updateOrderNumbers(draggedContext) {
    if (draggedContext.index < draggedContext.futureIndex) {  
      for (let i = draggedContext.index; i < draggedContext.futureIndex; i++) {
        let swapIndex = this.orderTableData[i].sortOrder;
        this.orderTableData[i].sortOrder = this.orderTableData[i+1].sortOrder ;
        this.orderTableData[i+1].sortOrder = swapIndex;
      }
    }

    if (draggedContext.index > draggedContext.futureIndex) {
      for (let i = draggedContext.index; i > draggedContext.futureIndex; i--) {
        let swapIndex = this.orderTableData[i].sortOrder;
        this.orderTableData[i].sortOrder = this.orderTableData[i+1].sortOrder;
        this.orderTableData[i+1].sortOrder = swapIndex;
      }
    }
 }
```

This method gets called from here

```
 onMoveCallback(evt){
    this.updateOrderNumbers(evt.draggedContext)
    this.checkForChanges()
  }
```

And here is the element that is triggering the call.

```
<draggable v-model="orderTableData" :move="onMoveCallback" tag="tbody">
```

Comment: There should be no difference in behaviour between `var` and `let` in that code. Maybe you’re using a buggy compiler. By “undefined”, do you mean there’s an error about the variable not existing, that the variable exists and has the value `undefined` (how did you check?), or that one of the `this.sortTableData[…]`s involving `i` is `undefined`? If there’s an error message, please show it and its stack trace.

Comment: Where do you get `undefined`?

Comment: I checked in both Chrome and Firefox to debug and in both browsers i is just not being assigned the value. In the for loop I tried to explicitly set i = 1 and it still was showing as undefined when I debugged in Chrome. There are no errors until I try to access an object  from the array but that makes sense because it is trying to resolve orderTableData[undefined] .sortOrder

Comment: In both for loops in the first code block i is equal to undefined @VLAZ

Comment: Is there a compile step, i.e. you’re looking at source-mapped code in the debugger? Try `console.log(i)`. (Especially with the `i = 1; i < 2` version.)

Comment: @Ry- You are right it is the debugger console.log shows the right value thank you

Comment: This looks like transpiler issue that doesn't generate the correct source map for the duplicate `i`s. Please report a bug with the appropriate part of your toolchain :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that FireFox and Chrome are unable to determine the value of a variable initialized with let inside of a for loop in this circumstance, but they are able to determine its value if you initialize the variable with var inside of the for loop.